# What determines the content of Doxygen namespace members page?

Tags: doxygen

I generate doxygen documentation in Linux and Windows. However, there is a difference in the "Namespace Members" section between the resulting generated documentation.

**In the generated Linux documentation:**

In the "Namespace Members" section, in the "All" tab, when I click on the letter "a", the displayed page is named as follows:

```
namespacemembers.html
```

In the "Namespace Members" section, in the "All" tab, when I click on the letter "e", the displayed page is named as follows:

```
namespacemembers_e.html
```

The same goes for any other letters I click on, so when I click on the letter "g", the displayed page is:

```
namespacemembers_g.html
```

**In the generated Windows documentation:**

In the "Namespace Members" section, in the "All" tab, when I click on the letter "a", the displayed page is named as follows:

```
namespacemembers.html#index_a
```

In the "Namespace Members" section, in the "All" tab, when I click on the letter "e", the displayed page is named as follows:

```
namespacemembers.html#index_e
```

The same goes for any other letters I click on, so when I click on the letter "g", the displayed page is:

```
namespacemembers.html#index_g
```

In other words, in Linux, there is a new page created for every namespace member alphabetic list, whereas in Windows, there is a single page 
created consisting of all the namespace members, organised by alphabetic list.

My question is: is this decided by some property in the Doxyfile and, if so, by which one ?

Comment: Are you using the same version on both windows and linux?

Comment: Also are you using the identical Doxyfile files in both cases, when not what are the differences?

Comment: I am using the same version on both windows and linux. I do not have access to the windows machine on which the documentation is run - I am told that it uses the same file as the Linux one, but I cannot check it myself. That's why I want to know what properties may be causing this and inform the people who have access to that file so they can change it if necessary.

Comment: Please check the versions used again (look in the index.html file, near the bottom there should be the version used). It will, normally, also show up when you look at the HTML pages. In case the problem persists please create a minimal self-contained example (source+config file in a tar or zip) that allows us to reproduce the problem (e,g, on the doxygen forum or in bugzilla as bug report).

Comment: The version is 1.8.10 on both Windows and Linux. I will try get access to the Windows machine to obtain the config file. However, of the behaviours I have described above, which out of the Linux and Windows namespacemembers documentation is correct ?

Comment: All quite hard to tell. With the 1.8.10 version I get differences between Windows and Linux (namespacemembers_c.html#index_c and namespacemembers_0x63.html#index_c) in the current version (1.8.13) I get in both cases namespacemembers_c.html#index_c